# Parsing email and phone number entities?

Tags: ibm-watson, chatbot, watson-conversation

Is there a way to train Watson to recognize email entities and phone numbers without resorting to regular expresses?

Comment: Maybe you'd like to know about the new release for entities in Watson Conversation, check my edit please.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Previously:**

> Steven, I had the same doubt a few months ago. IBM Watson Conversation
>   doesn't have System entities for phone numbers or e-mail address, *not
>   yet*. Anyway, it is a good idea for creating new System entities,
>   right? We can give ideas with feedback for IBM.
>
> But, one contour solution is to use context variables and create new
>   entities.  Try to create one entity like `@mail`, and add the values
>   `@gmail.com`, `@hotmail.com`, `@outlook.com`, and any e-mail that you
>   want to recognize.
>
> *And you will use with the condition like:*
>
> ```
> if @mail, response: Your e-mail is $email
> ```
>
> for recognizing the e-mail address, but for saving the e-mail you
>   will need to create one Regex inside the `context` variable like:
>
> ```
> "email": "<? input.text.extract('[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+(\\.[a-zA-Z]+){1,}',0)?>"
> ```
>
> *Now, for `phone` numbers:*
>
> You can activate the System Entity `@sys-number`, and you will get
>   just a few numbers, like 11 numbers and save inside one context
>   variable too.
>
> Create one condition with `@sys-number AND
>   input.text.find('^[^\\d]*[\\d]{11}[^\\d]*$',0)')` for find the number
>   and `sys-number` for recognize the numbers by user.

**EDIT:** (With new release notes - In *BETA* version):

**Now, IBM Watson Conversation have Patterns for Entities and we can use for getting email address, phone numbers, etc.**

**Now**, when you create one new `@entity`, you can *optionally* inform that you want to use `Pattern` or `Synonymous`, so, you will create one new entity, in my example, @contactInfo, and the values with `patterns` for getting the **mail** or **phone** values, for example:

[image]

And, after the Watson training your changes, check works perfectly in Try it Now:

[image]

- Pattern for mail: `\b[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,}\b`, e.g test@gmail.com
- Patter for USPhones: `(\d{3})-(\d{3})-(\d{4})`, e.g. `800-426-4968`

See more about Creating entities [here](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/entities.html#creating-entities).